# Puppet agent: "Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not render to json: source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8"

Tags: json, utf-8, puppet

We have a Puppet server running that services a couple of hundred Windows servers. The installed Puppet agent is 6.x. On almost all of the servers 'puppet agent -t' works fine, with a few exceptions exhibiting the same issue.

When I start clean, the Puppet agent connects with the server, receives a certificate and downloads all of the facts and what not. This works. Then the agent loads the facts and after a while I get an error message:

```
C:\>puppet agent -t
Info: Using configured environment 'windows'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Retrieving locales
Info: Loading facts
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not render to json: source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8
C:\>
```

If I run the Puppet agent in debug mode, although I could have missed it because there's a lot of output, all it shows is that it's resolving facts, and then the above message appears and the agent run stops. The last fact (according to debug output) that is being resolved is consistently:

```
Debug: Facter: resolving processor facts.
Debug: Facter: fact "hardwareisa" has resolved to "x64".
Debug: Facter: fact "processorcount" has resolved to 2.
Debug: Facter: fact "physicalprocessorcount" has resolved to 1.
Debug: Facter: fact "processor0" has resolved to "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2643 v2 @ 3.50GHz".
Debug: Facter: fact "processors" has resolved to {
  count => 2,
  isa => "x64",
  models => [
    "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2643 v2 @ 3.50GHz"
  ],
  physicalcount => 1
}.
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not render to json: source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8
```

However, I'm in doubt if that is the culprit because IIRC Puppet does not really run things sequential.

I don't understand how the same thing can work on one server, but not on another, even when having the same agent version. How can I find out what is the source of the error message?

Comment: Are you using any custom or external facts?

Comment: Yes we use custom facts. There are quite a number of them to make Puppet usable on Windows (DSC, Chocolatey, etc), so I was hoping for some quick way to point me to the issue.

Comment: Did you write them, or are they coming from official modules?

Comment: Can't say for sure because I didn't set this up. I think most are (look) official, but others are home grown for sure. I'd have to check this tomorrow and I'll ask my colleagues about it. (I sure hope they didn't modify the official modules by adding their own facts..)

Comment: You could try turning on `--debug` logging for the agent.  You could also perform just fact determination to see whether that fails, maybe `puppet facts --verbose --debug --render-as json`.

Comment: Is this related to https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-8187? There is almost certainly some binary data being passed around somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's *directly* related tho that ticket, but it's clearly somehow related.

Comment: However, a colleague went through all custom facts and found the one that had illegal chars in it. They are probably copy-pasted from the web, I've seen that happen before (that even was with invisible chars). So I'm unsure how he found the issue, I expect he just ran all our custom facts by hand which is a drag if you have a number of them. I wish Puppet would just say which fact is an issue: it knows which one it is when it encounters it...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an ancient topic but the resolution in my case was confirming that each of the custom facts was encoded in UTF-8. We discovered that a single fact file was encoded differently and re-encoding it as UTF-8 fixed our issues.